# How to run C program from bash script with one or more arguments?

Tags: c, bash, shell

This is my first time trying to create a bash script and I'm a bit confused.

I'm trying to run my c program from a bash script where the c program can take one or multiple arguments. If the c program takes 1 argument it will print the first n prime numbers depending on what was typed in. If it takes multiple arguments it will print the first n prime numbers of the largest integer argument and then the prime numbers between all possible ranges of the arguments. I'm having issues calling my c program with my bash script. Right now I'm just trying to have it find the largest integer and then print the first n integers:

```
file=$1
max=$2

shift
for arg in "$@"
do
    if [ $arg -gt $max ]; then
      max=$arg
    fi
done

for file in $path
do
    ./app "$file" "$max"
done
```

When I run the bash script if I type:

```
bash ./prime.sh ./prime 4 3 1
```

I should get: `2, 3, 5, 7`

I did not include the c code because that's currently working.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `./prime`?

Comment: Where do you set `$path`?

Comment: Is the name of your C program `./app` or `./prime`? What does `./app` do?

Comment: ./prime is what I used to call the c program. I was thinking I just took the first argument `./prime` and used that to execute the program. So I need to set the path in the bash script? I was looking at a couple other questions and saw them use `./app` so I assumed that was some way to call a program in a bash script.

Comment: Why do you set `file=$1` and then use `for file in $path` instead of using that?

Comment: I forgot to change the name when looking at other questions for help. I changed `file=$1` to `path=$1` but still having issues.

Comment: You only need the `for` loop if you're putting multiple C programs in `$1` and you want to run all of them, e.g. `./prime.sh './prime ./fibonacci' 4 3 1`

Comment: @jj2593: Assuming that your C program is `app`, you say that it takes 1 argument, but you are passing two arguments to it: $file and the largest of the subsequent arguments, in your case `4`. If `app` is not your C-program, but another script, you should post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `for` loop, just do:

```
"$path" "$max"
```

to run the program in `$path` with the argument `$max`.

I don't know what `./app` is, but you don't need to run another program to execute a C program.

Comment: Thanks! I could have sworn I tried that but obviously not!